# ios8 UIButton inside UIScrollview not clickable

Tags: uiscrollview, ios8, uibutton, scroll, clickable

I have seen many post regarding this type of issue .I tried many solutions but none of them worked for me. I am going through a strange situation.

I have created layout using storyboard. Storyboard contains UIScrollview. UIScrollview is having many views. Inside one view I am having 3 buttons. When I am trying to click buttons, they are working in iphone 6 but not working in iphone 5 and iphone 5s .

**Iphone 6**

Iphone 6 screen is bigger in height. So when I am launching screen in iphone 6 , then view which is having 3 buttons is visible on screen without any need of scrolling.

[image: View is visible without any need of scrolling]

In this case I am able to click buttons and actions are getting triggered for all 3 buttons.

**Iphone 5 and Iphone 5s**

Iphone screen is small so view is not visible at the time screen launched.

[image: button view not visible right now]

When I scrolls it up then view appears with 3 buttons.

[image]

Now I am not able to click any button. Actions are not triggering on clicking buttons now.

Please someone help me out. I tried all the possible thing but not finding any solution.

This question is different from existing questions regarding UIScrollview and UIButton clicking issue .

It might be possible that it is happening because of iOS8 only.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. I am not able to get any solution till now. Anyone please provide exact solution.